# laravel 4 how to retrieve logged in users data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationships

I'm a real newbie to Laravel but I'm loving it so far. I'm struggling on thing however, I want to retrieve the data for the user that is logged in and I am not sure how to go about this.

I have a few tables but I'll keep it basic for now, I have projects table and a users table, I've defined the relationships between these two in the models as so:

user.php

```
public function projects() {
    return hasMany('project');

}
```

project.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

class Project extends Eloquent
{
    public function user()
    {
        return belongsTo('user');
    }
}
```

I know I can do the following to retrieve all projects in the database with a `foreach` loop, however this doesn't retrieve the logged in users projects:

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')->get();
```

I saw one tutorial which wasn't very in depth but he said to access the model query I would have to use the following command:

```
$project = User::all()->projects;
```

However this hasn't worked either. Can anyone point me into the right direction with real tutorials or post simple examples?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are the projects of your logged in user:

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    $projects = Auth::user()->projects;
}
```

And this must be in your relation:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function projects() {

        return this->hasMany('Project');

    }
}
```

You also need to add $this to your Project relation:

```
class Project extends Eloquent
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Comment: amazing thank you! worked perfectly, love laravel makes everything so damn simple ;)

Comment: Nice. Enjoy Laravel! :)